# Group rows of dataframe according to dictionary in pandas and sum corresponding numerators

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, group-by

I have a dataframe of error codes, numerators, and their denominators as well as a dictionary of each possible error code and its overarching error type. I'd like to group the error codes in the dataframe by the error type, sum their numerators, and keep the column of denominators as is. I've tried

```
grouped = day1_xione.set_index('error_code').groupby(by=map_values,axis=1).sum().reset_index()
grouped
```

but it only keeps the error codes and doesn't group them by type. This is what a sample of the data looks like:

Dataframe:

| error_code | Numerator | Denominator |
| --- | --- | --- |
| POWER CYCLE ON | 5 | 10 |
| POWER OFF | 1 | 10 |
| PANIC - PANIC -PANIC_1 | 5 | 10 |
| TEMP_HIGH-TEMP | 0 | 10 |
| UNKNOWN-Reason_Unknown | 9 | 10 |

for as many error codes that show up, 56 errors. Each error code is a string that directly matches a code in the dictionary.

Dictionary:

```
map_values = 
{'POWER CYCLE ON' : 'POWER RESET',
'POWER OFF': 'POWER RESET',
'PANIC - PANIC -PANIC_1': 'DEVICE PANIC',
'TEMP_HIGH-TEMP': 'OTHER',
'UNKNOWN-Reason_Unknown': 'OTHER'}
```

for 57 codes and 10 types.

Desired Output:

| error_code | Numerator | Denominator |
| --- | --- | --- |
| POWER RESET | 6 | 10 |
| DEVICE PANIC | 5 | 10 |
| OTHER | 9 | 10 |

for all of the error codes that show up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close, you need to `groupby` the mapped values using `map` and use `agg` for aggregation with different functions (`sum` and `first`)

```
(df.groupby(df['error_code'].map(map_values))
   .agg({'Numerator': 'sum', 'Denominator': 'first'})
   .reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
     error_code  Numerator  Denominator
0  DEVICE PANIC          5           10
1         OTHER          9           10
2   POWER RESET          6           10
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems like it should work (I do get the columns I'd need, but no rows), but I think I'm still left with a data problem. Even after manually checking both my dataframe and my dictionary to ensure that the error codes match, python won't recognize them as matches. I even tried just doing a join and that data won't cooperate with that either.

Comment: Please provide an example for which it doesn't work and the expected output

Comment: I was able to fix the issue by converting all strings to be entirely in uppercase letters.